# C++ templates and assignment

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a class:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class FixedNum
{
    public:
        FixedNum& operator+= (const FixedNum& n);   
};
```

I want to define a `operator+=` that can accept `FixedNum<T, N2>`, where `N2` probably not equal to `N`. How can I do it? I'm confused with templates, GCC says *prototype for ... does not match any in class* whatever I do.

Comment: FixedNum<T,N> and FixedNum<T,N2> are different types.  You will need a helper class that will accept the two differing types.

Comment: Template variable `N` is an `int`. It can take any `int` value. Finally its the same type `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T, int N>
class FixedNum
{
public:

  template <int N2>
  FixedNum& operator+= (const FixedNum<T,N2>& n);
};

template<typename T, int N>
template<int N2>
FixedNum<T,N> & FixedNum<T,N>::operator+= (const FixedNum<T,N2>& n)
{
  ...
  return(*this);
}
```

Note that this can not change N; if you want to change N, then you're using the wrong approach.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to make it a template:

```
template <int N2>
FixedNum& operator+= (const FixedNum<T, N2>& n);
```

Comment: Here's how the method is implemented:
`template <typename T, int N, int N2>
FixedNum<T, N>& FixedNum<T, N>::operator+=(const FixedNum<T, N2>& g) {...}`
GCC still shows an error.

Comment: You need two level of templates: one for the class, and one for the operator. Something like `template<typename T, int N> template<int N2> FixedNum<T,N> & FixedNum<T,N>::operator+= (const FixedNum<T,N2>& n) { ... }`